# Get ldap server ip address and port no in centos

Tags: linux, centos, ldap

I am trying to get IP address and port number of open LDAP server in CentOS. I could not find the proper documentation for it.
Please help me on how to get LDAP server IP address and port number in CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address of any LDAP server is the IP address of the host it is running in.

The port number is 389 for plaintext or 636 for SSL.